# how to handle activities laucher using android

Tags: android

Well, I have 3 pages, Login, Splash and MainActivity, so if the user is not Logged it has to rise the Login Page after the Splash, so inside of my Splash I check with the Realm Database if a field is filled and if it has it means that the user is already logged, but if is not, rises the Login Page and works fine, but if the user exit from the app(not finishing the app) just exit, and erase the data on Configurations, how to handle this when he comeback to the App? It would be on `OnPause`? There's any other way to avoid the user just erase the data?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
String token_result = new Realmbase().RetrieveToken(CurrentActivity.this);
    if(token_result.equals("NODATA")){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else {
        //Continue in the same Activity
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It is better save the data
```

1) Save process ID in shared preference:

```
SharedPreferencesUtils.getInstance().putInt(SharedPreferencesUtils.APP_PROCESS_ID, android.os.Process.myPid());
```

2) When application is launched from launcher after clear from recent task then do:

```
int previousProcessID = mSharedPreferencesUtils.getInt(SharedPreferencesUtils.APP_PROCESS_ID);

int currentProcessID = android.os.Process.myPid();

if ((previousProcessID == currentProcessID)) {
    // This ensures application not killed yet either by clearing recent or anyway
} else {
    // This ensures application killed either by clearing recent or by anyother means
}
```